# How to put data from sqlite to PyQt5 treewidget without duplications

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, qtreeview, qtreewidget

I have some problems to put data from `sqlite` in a `QTreeWidget`.
In my database I have many many rows with 3 columns and wants them organize in a `QTreeWidget`.
My database looks like:

[image: databasescheme]

and I want to organize them like this:

[image: treeview]

It is important that there is no child duplication if child has the same parent. In my imagination it seems so easy to do that, but nothing I do is working.

I fetched the data from the database but what I have to do now?
Thank you

Comment: Hi! hope this can help, he is manually inserting the data, you can loop on your fetched data quite easily. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LW__NuulfxE

Comment: Video is good but helps me not. Now I try it with some for loops but it is not easy. The biggest problem is to make sure that I get no duplicates in the tree.

Comment: I found a solution that works for me. Where i can post my code? Should I make an "answer" or "edit" the first post? I want to show what if have done.